# Sitemap File for Multiple Languages

Tags: seo, google-search-console, sitemap, xml-sitemap, hreflang

Hi Currently my site is in 3 languages:- English, French, Dutch.

My main sitemap file is example.com/sitemap.xml

I have 2 questions:

1. Since I don't have a root folder for other languages (I only have one root folder), my question is how do I implement a sitemap for other languages?

Should I just add my URLs into the main sitemap.xml file? ( which includes English language URLs)

2. If I use Google's 3rd method of implementing href lang tag via sitemap method like mentioned [here.](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/crawling/localized-versions#expandable-3)

Should I still add my URLs into the main sitemap file ( sitemap.xml)?

Comment: What does a root folder have to do with a sitemap file?

Comment: Since sitemap file has to be in the root folder right? I dont have root folders for my other languages

Comment: You can have multiple sitemap files in your root folder with different names,